# compute diff of rows with NAs values in data frame using R

Tags: r

I have data frame (9000 x 304) but it looks like to this :

| date | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1997-01-01 | 8.720551 | 10.61597 |
| 1997-01-02 | na | na |
| 1997-01-03 | 8.774251 | na |
| 1997-01-04 | 8.808079 | 11.09641 |

I want to calculate the values data such as :

- first <- data[i-1,] - data[i-2,]
- second <- data[i,] - data[i-1,]
- third <- data[i,] - data[i-2,]

I want to ignore the NA values and if there is na I want to get the last value that is not na in the column.

For example in the second diff i = 4 from column b :
11.09641 - 10.61597 is the value of b_diff on 1997-01-04

This is what I did but it keeps generating data with NA :

```
first <- NULL
for (i in 3:nrow(data)){
  first <-rbind(first, data[i-1,] - data[i-2,])
}

second <- NULL
for (i in 3:nrow(data)){
  second <- rbind(second, data[i,] - data[i-1,])
}

third <- NULL
for (i in 3:nrow(data)){
  third <- rbind(third, data[i,] - data[i-2,])
}
```

It can be a way to solve it with aggregate function but I need a solution that can be applied on big data and I can't specify each colnames separately. Moreover my colnames are in foreign language.

Thank you very much ! I hope I gave you all the information you need to help me, otherwise, let me know please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fill` to replace NAs with the closest value, and then use `across` and `lag` to compute the new variables. It is unclear as to what exactly is your expected output, but you can also replace the default value of lag when it does not exist (e.g. for the first value), using `lag(.x, default = ...)`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  fill(a, b) %>% 
  mutate(across(a:b, ~ lag(.x) - lag(.x, n = 2), .names = "first_{.col}"),
         across(a:b, ~ .x - lag(.x), .names = "second_{.col}"),
         across(a:b, ~ .x - lag(.x, n = 2), .names = "third_{.col}"))

        date        a        b first_a first_b second_a second_b  third_a third_b
1 1997-01-01 8.720551 10.61597      NA      NA       NA       NA       NA      NA
2 1997-01-02 8.720551 10.61597      NA      NA 0.000000  0.00000       NA      NA
3 1997-01-03 8.774251 10.61597  0.0000       0 0.053700  0.00000 0.053700 0.00000
4 1997-01-04 8.808079 11.09641  0.0537       0 0.033828  0.48044 0.087528 0.48044
```